# Remove lines containing non-numeric entries in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I have a sample data file (sample.log) that has entries

```
0.0262
0.0262
0.7634
5.7262
0.abc02
```

I need to filter out the lines that contain non-numeric data, in the above lines, the last entry.

I tried this

```
sed 's/[^0-9]//g' sample.log
```

It removes the non-numeric line but also removes the decimal values, the output  I get is

```
00262
00262
07634
57262
```

How can I get the original values retained after eliminating the non-numeric lines. Can I use tr or awk

Comment: `grep '[^0-9\.]' yourfile`

Comment: This prints the line that contains non-numeric values, not the other way.

Comment: so add a -v to invert the match

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this job robustly with sed or grep or any other tool that doesn't understand numbers, you need awk instead:

```
$ cat file
1e3
1f3
0.1.2.3
0.123

$ awk '$0==($0+0)' file
1e3
0.123
```

The best you could do with a sed solution would be:

```
$ sed '/[^0-9.]/d; /\..*\./d' file
0.123
```

which removes all lines that contains anything other than a digit or period then all those that contain 2 or more periods (e.g. an IP address) but that still can't recognize the exponent notation as a number.

If you have hex input data and GNU awk (see [@dawg's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35822141/remove-lines-containing-non-numeric-entries-in-bash/35823418?noredirect=1#comment59326004_35823418)):

```
$ echo "0x123" | awk --non-decimal-data '$0==($0+0){printf "%s => %f\n", $0, ($0+0)}'
0x123 => 291.000000
```

Comment: The `awk` solution is robust. Usage note: hex strings will be converted to and interpreted as decimal floats: `echo "0x123" | awk '$0==($0+0){printf "%s => %f\n", $0, ($0+0)}'` Also, `inf` and `nan` are filtered as True. Otherwise -- completely robust +1

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
awk '/^[[:digit:].]+$/{print $0}' file
```

Or, you negate that (and add potential `+` or `-` if that is in your strings):

```
awk '/[^[:digit:].+-]/{next} 1' file
```

Or, same logic with `sed`:

```
sed  '/[^[:digit:].+-]/d' file
```

---

Ed Morton's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35823418/298607) is robust. Given:

```
$ cat nums.txt
    1e6          
.1e6
1E6
.001
.
0.001
.1.2
1abc2
0.0
-0
-0.0
0x123
0223
011
NaN
inf
abc

$ awk '$0==($0+0) {printf "%s => %f\n", $0, ($0+0)}
       $0!=($0+0) {notf[$0]++;}
       END {for (e in notf) print "\""e"\""" not a float"}' /tmp/nums.txt
        1e6           => 1000000.000000
.1e6 => 100000.000000
1E6 => 1000000.000000
.001 => 0.001000
0.001 => 0.001000
0.0 => 0.000000
-0 => 0.000000
-0.0 => 0.000000
0x123 => 291.000000
0223 => 223.000000
011 => 11.000000
NaN => nan
inf => inf
".1.2" not a float
"1abc2" not a float
"abc" not a float
"." not a float
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with grep if you discard any line that contains any letter:

```
grep -v [a-z] test
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$ sed -i '/.*[a-z].*/d' sample.log
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but to be more general I changed this to sed -i '/[a-z]/d' sample.log

Comment: @kris: 'Twould be better, perhaps, to use `sed -i '/[^0-9.]/d' …`, where the regex looks for anything that isn't a digit or dot (you could add `+` or `-` if you need to).  Alternatively, you get into very much more complex regular expressions that recognize valid numbers with exponents etc.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/[^0-9.]/d' file
```

However this may give a false positive on say an IP address i.e. allowing more than one `.`.

Using your test data:

```
sed '/^[0-9]\.[0-9]\{4\}$/!d' file
```

Would only match a digit, followed by a `.` followed by 4 digits.